# Check if a certain file exists in CFS from Java code

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

After some online example I tried the following:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.default.name","cfs://x.x.x.x:9000/"); // actual ip in here
config.set("fs.cfs.impl","org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.fs.CassandraFileSystem");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
System.out.println(fs.exists(new Path("cfs:///path/to/file")));
```

But I can't find the Jar containing `CassandraFileSystem`. I wonder if it's an old version or something. I do have the CQL driver in my classpath, i.e., the Gradle dependency `com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.0.1`, but the class `CassandraFileSystem` does not ship with this artifact.

What's the idiom to check for file existence in CFS? Using Datastax Enterprise 4.0.1.

**EDIT**: just to be clear, the problem here seems to be finding the class `CassandraFileSystem`. I can't find it anywhere in the DSE jar although its usage is documented. Was it deprecated? Is it in some other jar besides `com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.0.1`?

Comment: do you have Datastax Enterprise 4.0.1 jar in class-path?

Comment: I have 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.0.1' but apparently that's not it. Is it in maven or do I have to copy it from one of my nodes?

Comment: If you have maven project then add following maven dependency into pom.xml  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>${cassandra.driver.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: I just said I have that artifact in my project, the class I need is not in that artifact.

Answer (score -1):

If you have maven project then add following maven dependency into pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>${cassandra.driver.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

otherwise add jar into project class path.

Comment: Yeah the `CassandraFileSystem` is not there.

Comment: then do that what I have explained above.

Comment: You don't understand what I am saying: the class `CassandraFileSystem` is __not__ in that artifact.

Comment: please look into it
http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/java-code-to-perform-cfs-file-operations-from-remote-system-is-not-working

Comment: Uhm what exactly? I still can't find the class `CassandraFileSystem` anywhere!

Answer (score -1):

CFS is a component of DSE, so you need add DSE jar files to your class path. You can check a file by this command.

bin/dse hadoop fs -lsr cfs://localhost/path_to_file

Comment: The question is how to do this from Java code. I know how DSE works, we've been using it in prod for a while now. I found examples of __Java code__ but can't find the classes used in those examples. Can I be clearer?

Comment: You need add dse.xxxx.jar and related jar files to your class path. CFS is inside DSE jar, so you may need add DSE jar dependencies (at resources/xxxx/lib) as well, but those dependencies my cause conflict to your application lib. We may try to separate CFS to a standalone project, so it's easy to plug it in other application. For now, you need try and test with all those jar files in your class path.